# Managing AWS S3 Access via Mobile App

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm creating an app that utilizes a feature similar to instagram -- users can upload images and view others'. They also need to be able to delete only their own.

I plan to store these images in S3. What's the safest way to allow users to upload, download, and delete their own? My current plan is to authenticate users through my own system, then exchange that login token for AWS Cognito credentials, which can upload and download to/from my S3 bucket.

Deleting I think will be more difficult. I imagine I will have clients send a request to a server that processes it, makes sure the requested deletion is allowed for that client, and then sends the request to S3 using admin credentials.

Is this a feasible way of managing all this, and how best can I disallow users from uploading random things to my bucket? I want them only to be able to upload images associated with their account and with my app, but presumably with the Cognito credentials they could upload anything.

Thanks, and let me know if I wasn't clear on anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Amazon Cognito, your mobile application users will **assume an Identity and Access Management (IAM) role**, which gives them permissions to access AWS resources.

A role could, for example, grant access to an Amazon S3 bucket to allow them to upload and download pictures. You can then limit their access to the S3 bucket such that they can only perform actions on objects within their own directory.

Here is an example policy that insert grants access to subdirectories based on their Cognito identity:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, you can allow the mobile app to directly interface with S3 for uploads, downloads and deletes, rather than having to request it through a back-end service. This will allow your app to scale without having to have as many servers (so it's cheaper, too!)

For more details, see:

- [Understanding Amazon Cognito Authentication Part 3: Roles and Policies](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies)

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! Is it feasible to give every user their own directory, even if there are hundreds of thousands of users?

Comment: Yes. In fact, there are no such things as "directories" in S3. Rather, the directory path is appended to the front of the key name. It still "looks" like there are directories, and you can list them, but they don't actually exist. This means there is no limit on the number of directories, just like there's no limit on the number of objects stored in an S3 bucket. (DropBox uses S3, and imagine how many users and files they must have.) Go for it!